# Oracle APEX - Uploading Custom Classes / JARS

Tags: java, oracle, jar, oracle-apex

I became aware of APEX (application express) quite recently.

I've gone through the getting started, and youtube videos very quickly and I've seen you can do quite a few things through their wizard like interface.

My question though is are you table to upload custom java code to the actual Database for running in your APEX applications?

Apologies for the newbie question, but the getting started information and initial youtube videos didn't answer this for me.

Resources I have looked at:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/apex-getting-started-1863613.html
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/apex-videos-1866618.html

Comment: Since the oracle db supports Java, you can compile java code in there, yes. You could call the code through plsql then, so it is accessible through apex. But apex doesn't really have anything to with java, so I wonder why you ask? Don't forget that the XE database does NOT support java by the way!

Comment: Aha, so you need to compile your code directly on the oracle db.

Comment: I'm far from a specialist on the matter, I just know of it but never had to use it so far. I suppose the docs are as good a place as any to find out: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chone.htm#BABCJIED

Comment: Yep..it's a very muddy topic. I also looked at some other posts and I was amazing to see that almost all development takes place as PL/SQL or through their APEX web IDE.. that many developers say is a nightmare of debug, etc.

Comment: APEX is Oracle DATABASE tool. So what is amazing that most development takes place in PL/SQL?

Comment: I haven't had any debugging issues. Apex has great debugging tools and easily allows logging additional messages. I haven't had issues with plsql and debugging it. Have you?